# What word that to describe Query+Response

Tags: technology

In computer science, what would be the right word to describe an object that includes a query and the query's response?

Thank you

Comment: what's the context? would "poll" make sense?

Comment: Without looking it up, I would say that it is a *transaction*.

Comment: About "transaction": that is what I thought about in the first place but isn't transaction a financial term for "transfer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though Mick has already defined

> transaction

as the word. I would like to describe that it seems that it is a financial term but it is a terminology  in RDBMS.

A transaction is a logical unit of work that contains one or more SQL statements. A transaction is an atomic unit. The effects of all the SQL statements in a transaction can be either all committed (applied to the database) or all rolled back (undone from the database).

Hope it helps..

Comment: That's the obvious problem. I didn't have time to elaborate.

Comment: @Mick I did it on your behalf.. :)

Comment: Good-oh! +1 ;-)